# FOSUserBundle do action once the user registration ius confirmed

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm newbie to the FOSUserBundle which I'm using on my Symfony2 project.

What I want is to make some actions in my system (persist some kind of information) when a user has been successfully registered, that is, once he as confirmed the registration process.

How must I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can register an event listener to listen to the registration confirmed event and handle any post registration actions there.

FOSUserBundle Events: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php

Symfony2 Event Listener:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html